hide statusbar in flutter

When I want to hide the status bar, it gets hidden but a black bar takes its place. How can I fix this?
'''
void main()async {

  runApp(MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
}

'''
and I use all of these feilds :
'''
SystemUiMode.immersive
SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky
SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge
SystemUiMode.leanBack
SystemUiMode.manual , overlays: []

'''

For single page (in page file):
@override
void initState() {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
    [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
super.dispose();

}
For All pages (in main.dart):
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
  home: SplashScreen()));
  }

Dont forget to import 'package:flutter/services.dart'

as weird as it is, you need to wrap your page with SafeArea.
body: SafeArea(
  top: false,
  bottom: false,
  left: false,
  right: false,
  maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
  child: child,
),


Consider this as your cheat sheet:
  // Visible Status Bar & Bottom Navigation Bar Both
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: <SystemUiOverlay>[SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom],
  );

  // Hide Status Bar & Bottom Navigation Bar Both
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: <SystemUiOverlay>[],
  );

  // Hide Status Bar & Visible Bottom Navigation Bar
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: <SystemUiOverlay>[SystemUiOverlay.bottom],
  );

  // Hide Bottom Navigation Bar & Visible Status Bar
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: <SystemUiOverlay>[SystemUiOverlay.top],
  );

